# No outlets working in the room.throws breakers when use extension cords

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

My bedroom outlets do not work at all. If we plug in extension cords to anything in that room it throws the breaker. Do I need new wiring or a new breaker box or both.

Comment: why are you assuming that wiring and breaker box require replacement?

Comment: who changed the wiring

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like other things on that circuit gave already pushed that breaker close to it's maximum load. Figure out what else that circuit feeds and start moving things to other circuits, unplugging, or turning off.

(I used to have this problem in my second apartment; one of the most convenient outlets for the vacuum was near capacity, and I had to make sure the stereo was turned off before turning the vac on or I'd blow the breaker.)